# e.force:navigateToObjectHome not working in different sandbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, navigation

I have developed a Lightning app that uses the force event : e.force:navigateToObjectHome to get the user to an object page. This event has been working fine in 3 sandbox so far but now that I am testing it in a 4th sandbox the event has stopped working.

When debugging this issue I found out that the event is undefined in Sandbox #2. What would trigger such an issue? I even added the event as an aura:dependency to my component, and it still does not work.

The app itself is contained in a VF page and I have used Joe Buschmann example on how to send force events to the VF page and have the page handle them: http://joebuschmann.com/salesforce-lightning-navigation-events-in-a-visualforce-page/

Comment: Thats insane . Did you try switching locker service off to see if thats causing issue or its a separate bug ?I think you will need to open a support case and escalate

Comment: Actually Locker Service was on in Sandbox 1 and off in Sandbox 2. However switching it didn't help.

Comment: Seems like the issue is with either the lightning app or the Visualforce page that contains them. I was able to fire the event when my component was by itself in  a Lightning record page.

Comment: Welp,  Mohit you saved my life once again with this blog post: http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2016/02/lightning-events-via-visualforce.html

The issue was with the Visualforce page where I was initially trying to retrieve event information doing this: 
    event.$params$.url
Changing it to:
    event.getParam('url')
Solved the issue.

I will update the post and post a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the handlers on the Visualforce page. Replacing $params$.scope with event.getParam('scope') fixed the issue.

I do not have an answer as to why one is better than the other and why the first option worked fine in 1 sandbox but not the other.